# Issue when using Xcode 11 running Canvas on macOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I have Catalina macOS version (10.15) installed and still the canvas is not showing up.

The error message I get from Xcode is

> Select a scheme that builds a target which contains the current file,
>   or add this file to a target that is built by the current scheme

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but did you check the **Use SwiftUI** checkbox when you created the project? Also, the error suggests the issue is related to your scheme? What file is it referring to?

Comment: For me, just a new vanilla iOS project with the SwiftUI checkbox checked.  It creates `ContentView.swift` (which is a SwiftUI view).  When this view is open, the preview pane on the right displays the error @BilalReffas quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I filled a Radar `FB6123260` please do that also. For me resetting the nvram worked and deleting derived data.

[Resetting Nvram](https://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-your-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html)

Deleting derived data:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Comment: I deleted Derived data without resetting Nvram. It worked for me.

Comment: I deleted file with your command in terminal but I still get that error message from Xcode. You filled a Radar but I don't know how to do that. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Add your new files to the compiled bundles as part of the build phases?
Not only does the target need to be set for the file- but it also has to be included in the compiled bundles..

Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> search for the file your are trying to work on